# How to prevent malfunction (memory leak) by disposing static methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I am using ASP.NET 4.0.

From last few weeks, few users are complaining that the application starts malfunctioning. The GridView suddenly starts showing contents of a DropDown control that the same user or another concurrent user might have accessed at any point of time in that day. Similarly, DropDown controls may get populated by RowID of the any old result-set instead of the actual items.

I came across an article: [Users seeing other users data in ASP.NET](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jorman/archive/2005/11/22/users-seeing-other-users-data-in-asp-net.aspx) where the author discusses about Static objects responsible for memory leak behavior.

It reminds me of a class in my project which is `Static` and contains `public static` methods. This class contains methods to populate a DropDown, return a DataSet for a query input or return a scalar object based on a query input.

Extract of this class is below:

```
public static class reuse
{
    public static void FillDropDownList(string Query, DropDownList DropDownName, string ConnectionStringParameter)
    {
        SqlDataReader dr;

        try
        {
            dbConnection.OpenConnection(ConnectionStringParameter);

            //Check whether the Drop Down has existing items. If YES, empty it.
            if (DropDownName.Items.Count > 0)
                DropDownName.Items.Clear();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query,dbConnection.cn);
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DropDownName.Items.Add("-- Select --");
            DropDownName.Items.Add("All");
            while (dr.Read())
                DropDownName.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());

            dr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            rpkCustomErrorHandler.GetScript(HttpContext.Current.Response,ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        dbConnection.CloseConnection();
    }
}
```

I want to know whether this is the cause of the malfunction I discussed above. If yes, is there any way to dispose Static Methods after the task of the method has finished. Do I need to change the class from Static to a default plain class?

**Edited**

I have another class which is also static and is used by the above class:

```
public static class dbConnection
{
    public static SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection();

    public static void OpenConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            cn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cnWebTwDrill"].ToString();

            if (cn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                cn.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;              
        }
    }
}
```

Shall I remove "Static" from the Connection Class and make call to this class by using a unique instance each time?

Comment: Your drop down is inside GridView? Could you provide some related aspx code?

Comment: No DropDown is not in GridView, but whenever I need to populate a DropDown or a GridView, I make a call to this class like: reuse.FillDropDownList("Select CustomersNames From Customer, ComboBox1);

Comment: I just realized that GridViews are populated by SQL DataSource which is unique for each GridView.

Comment: Having one user see another user's data can be caused by faulty caching strategies.

Comment: I am not using Caching? Is caching enabled by default, somewhere in Control's properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you've  shown us is an example of bad usage of static class/method. You put in a static method or class things that are to simple to fit in an object AND which DON'T REQUIRE state.

The functionality you have there should be split between the Business Layer (which will retrieve the data) and the UI/COntroller (in this case Page ) where you assign the data to the server control. All this operations are specific to a request, there is no reason to use a static method for that. Is just a sign of (bad) procedural programming. And when dealing with db access (or disposable objects) you should use the *using* statement. Something like this

```
using(var conex=GetConnection())
{
   try
   {
     conex.Open(); 
     //do stuff

    var cmd= new SqlCommand();//cfg command
    using (var rd= cmd.ExecuteReader())   
      {
           //do read
      }
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
    {
       //handle exception
    }
}
```

The *using* statement automatically calls Dispose at the end of the block. It's basically a shortcut for

```
try {}
finally{ //dispose }.
```

Comment: Totally agree that it is a bad design. Actually this class was in use in few Standalone applications and same people attached to this online application which I got to work on. What is the immediate solution for this class to handle concurrent connections without malfunctioning?

Comment: I've already told you. For the fastest way move the functionality in the Page_Load event handler, at least it will use the request data, but it's still bad coding. When dealing with concurrency static is the worst way and if you MUST use static then you need thread locking http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx .

Comment: That dbconnection class shouldn't exist at all.A db connection should NEVER be static, it means it's shared by EVERY request, which is really AWFUL. The example I gave above, contains the proper way to handle connections. Use them withing Page_Load in this particular case, until you get to refactor the application for proper layering.

Comment: If I want to make a Connection Class, what changes are needed in the above class. I am definitely going to implement your suggestions but every method needs to be tested. Till that time, what immediate solution I can do to get rid of this problem?

Comment: These are the immediate solutions, plain and simple. Just put that code directly where it's needed in the Page_Load. For much easier db handling I';d use a micro orm like Peta Poco. In fact I recommend it and you shouldn't have any problem in the future. Just stay away of static stuff, think 10x before making a method or class static

Comment: I am not following what you mean to paste entire code in PageLoad. The code in which you made corrections is a code to fill DropDowns.

Comment: No, that's a code which access the db AND fills the dorp down. You could take that code , change it to use every time a new instance of SqlConnection (or switch to PataPoco , as it's very simple to use) and put it in the Page_Load of hte page which displays the dropdown box.

Comment: I want to update the existing connection class as a Sealed Class and create a new connection instance each time it accesses any method in the previous (reuse) class. I also want to add Dispose() in the connection class. Will this work?

Comment: No, you can't call dispose until after you've finished with the connection. THe best you can do if you REALLY WANT to have that class (I don't understand WHY?!!) is just to return a new SqlConnection. You still have to do the 'using ' part where you actually use the connection

Answer (score 1):

Its not a question of leaking or disposing its a question of utilizing static objects with state.  This function is static, but it is not statefull all of the context of the operation is present in the call as such all of the objects in this class that are not parameters will be cleaned up automatically.  However if you defined some type of static data any users in the same app domain would share the value.   That being said you must be carefully any time you utilize statics as they are hard to test replace and are very difficult in multithreading situations.

Comment: What if I use GC.Collect() after each login to clear off any  resources that may have been left in memory and not disposed?

Comment: its not about disposal. GC collect will never delete static objects they are always reachable and there for not eligible for garbage collection.  The only time they go away is when the app domain goes away.

Comment: How to dispose Static Objects?

Comment: You don't and rerun told you why

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the error you're seeing is caused by a memory leak or a failure to Dispose of static objects.

However, to answer your question: the only way to free the memory held by static objects is to set the associated static references to null. After that, they won't be reachable, and the GC will take care of the rest.

Two things that might help with the actual problem:

1. Faulty caching strategies can cause unintentional data sharing (at the HTTP level or with the ASP.NET object cache, output caching, etc)
2. Be sure to use locking around all references to static objects that can be shared between threads, where one thread might write the object while another is reading it.

BTW, the static method in the OP does not appear to use any static objects; everything it touches seems to be passed as an argument. Static methods alone don't allocate or hold memory references.

**Update:**

Trying to share a single DB connection between page requests is a bug, and will almost certainly result in undefined behavior (for example, one page could issue a query, while another page reads the response). DB connections are already pooled by the runtime; you don't need to optimize that part on your own. Each page request should not only use a new `SqlConnection`, it should also call `Dispose()` on the connection object afterwards, to promptly release it back to the pool.

Comment: I am not using Caching at all. How to lock static objects? I am also noticing that error is coming when a GridView is refreshed by SQL DataSource. In this case I am not calling the above Static Class. I am worried I have a Static Connection class which is similar as above.

Comment: What is the immediate solution to the mentioned connection class till the time I remove it completely? Shall I add a "finally" after try..catch to dispose the connection object?

Comment: The immediate solution is to remove the conection class, it's a very simple task. You lose more time writing comments here than removing that class. It's bad design, bad code, bad everything.

Comment: Adding finally won't fix it. At a minimum, remove all static declarations from the class, fields and methods. Better to remove it all together, though.