# How to improve this reusable methods class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, concurrency

I have a class containing methods to fill DropDowns, return DataSet, return Scalar or simply excute a query. In one of my [older posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426086/how-to-prevent-malfunction-memory-leak-by-disposing-static-methods) in StackOverflow, I submitted a buggy code of the same class. Based on the advice of the contributors, I have improved the code and want to know whether this class is suitable to be used in a high-concurrent environment:

```
public sealed class reuse
{
    public void FillDropDownList(string Query, DropDownList DropDownName)
    {
        using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnection"].ConnectionString.ToString()))
            {
                SqlDataReader dr;
                try
                {
                    if (DropDownName.Items.Count > 0)
                        DropDownName.Items.Clear();

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, con);
                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (dr.Read())
                        DropDownName.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());

                    dr.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    CustomErrorHandler.GetScript(HttpContext.Current.Response,ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know whether to dispose Command and DataReader objects as well or they too will get automatically disposed with USING?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The the command/reader: they *would* be disposed by "using", but only if you **use** "using" for them, which you should.

Criticisms:

- you are mixing UI and data access horribly - the exception handling in particular gives no indication to the calling code (although personally I'd keep the control code separate too), and assumes the caller always wants that script-based approach (to me, if this code fails, things are very wrong: let that exception bubble upwards!)
- no mechanism for proper parameters; my suspicion then, is that you're concatenating strings to make a query - potential (but very real) risk of SQL injection
- you mention high-concurrent; if so, I would expect to see some cache involvement here
- for code maintenance reasons, I'd move all "create a connection" code to a central point - "DRY" etc; I wouldn't expect an individual method like this to concern itself with details like where the connection-string comes from

Frankly I'd just use dapper here, and avoid all these issues:

```
using(var connection = Config.OpenConnection()) {
     return connection.Query<string>(tsql, args).ToString();
}
```

(and let the caller iterate over the list, or use AddRange, or data-binding, whatever)

Comment: I have a Static Connection class but people suggested it is not suitable in a concurrent environment. There is a risk of SQL Injection and I am looking forward to use PetaPoco. What type of connection class you suggest of no ORM is used?

Comment: @RPK an actual static connection is indeed very dangerous - all I was saying was: move the code that creates a connection to a utility method. No need to duplicate that everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Generally agree with Marc's answer but I have some other comments and different angle. Hope my answer will be useful for you.

First, there is **nothing wrong in using static classes** and methods in concurrent environment as long as there is no need for any state information and no data is shared. In your case, filling up DropDownList, it is perfectly fine because you only need a list of strings and once that's done you can forget all about how you got it. There is also no interference between concurrent calls to static method if they do not access any static fields. Static methods are common across .NET framework and they are thread safe.

In my example below I do use one static field - log4net logger. It is still thread-safe because it does not carry any state and is merely a jump point to log4net library which itself is thread-safe. Do recommend at least looking at log4net - great logging lib.

It could only be unsafe if you tried to fill the same drop down list from two threads but then it would be also unsafe if this class was not static. Make sure drop downs are filled from one (main) thread.

Back to your code. **Mixing UI and data retrieval is not a good practice** as it makes code much less maintainable and less stable. Separate those two. [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) library might be a good way to simplify things. I have not used it myself so all I can tell is that it looks very handy and efficient. If you want/need to learn how stuff works don't use it though. At least not at first.

Having non-parametrized query in one string is potentially prone to SQL injection attacks but if that query is not constructed based on any direct user input, it should be safe. Of course you can always adopt parametrization to be sure.

Handling exception using

```
CustomErrorHandler.GetScript(HttpContext.Current.Response, ex.Message.ToString());
```

feels flaky and too complex for this place and may result in another exception. Exception when handling another exception means panic. I would move that code outside. If you need something here let it be a simple log4net error log and re-throw that exception.

If you only do one DB read there is no need for an explicit transaction. **As per connection object, it should not be static in any situation and be created on demand.** There is no performance penalty in that because .NET keeps a pool of ready to use connections and recycles those that were 'disposed'.

I believe that an example is always better than just explanations so here is how I would re-arrange your code.

```
public static class reuse
{
    static public readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("GeneralLog");

    public static void FillDropDownList(string query, string[] parms,  DropDownList dropDown)
    {
        dropDown.Items.Clear();
        dropDown.DataSource = GetData(query, parms);
        dropDown.DataBind();
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetData(string query, string[] parms)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnString()))
        {
            try
            {
                List<string> result = new List<string>();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parms);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.VisibleFieldCount > 0)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                        result.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                }
                dr.Close();
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Exception in GetData()", ex);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    private static string GetConnString()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnection"].ConnectionString.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maciej. I was thinking to use Log4Net but I didn't get time to explore it and also Dapper. I think the problem majorly lies in the Connection class, which too is Static and hold two Static Methods, viz: OpenConnection() and CloseConnection().

Comment: Yes, this is highly not recommended. Connection should be created on demand. There is no performance penalty in that because .NET keeps a pool of ready to use connections.